# Im Trying to log queries , doesnt matter if they're unprepared ones , for over 500 xml mapper files using jdk logger . (mybatis - spring )

Tags: java, spring, logging, mybatis, spring-mybatis

previously when I used to used ibatis , it was running fine just by adding java.sql to my logs.properties file in tomcat and that used to output the queries with their params to the log file .

now since I switched from ibatis to mybatis and also from spring 1.2 to spring 5 (i can't really tell where the problem came from at this point ) I'm not able to log queries as I used before. specifying java.sql in my logs.properties doesn't print out any logs to my file.

all my configurations are XML based.

The only way I'm able to log queries so far is through including the namespace of the XML mapper to my logs.properties file but this is just unrealistic for over 500 XML files that are in different locations at some point.

I'm trying to find a class that I can include in my logs.properties file that would be able to do the same job as java.sql

Comment: There is no such setting in MyBatis. Are you aware that you can set the log level against the package of the mappers? If, however, there are 500 packages, it may not be realistic either. If that is the case, you should consider using external logging tool like [jdbcdslog](https://github.com/adrianshum/jdbcdslog).

Comment: the thing i can't get my head around is why i used to be able to do that using java.sql and now i can't . and yea i dont have a single package for all my mappers even if i did for some reason pointing to a mapper location doesnt get me the logs as well it only works when i use the namespace

Comment: IIRC, there was no way to set different log level for a particular statement or mapper in iBATIS. It is possible with MyBatis' logging system. You didn't show any mapper, config, etc., but if the namespace is `xxx.yyy.MyMapper`, for example, the logger name should be `xxx.yyy`. If you don't use fully-qualified name as the namespace (like recommended in the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html)), this method won't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately this is legacy code and it's not following the naming convention , the only common thing between 100s of xml mappers is that they all exist in a mappers list in mybatis-config file , i dont know if that could help in any way @ave

Comment: @DanyAllaw Have you considered using JDBC logging library as I mentioned in my first comment?

Comment: I just implemented it and it was exactly what i was looking for , Thanks alot !
if you want to ,  go ahead and put your reply so i mark it as a solution @ave

Comment: I'm glad to know it worked! I posted a brief answer summarizing our comments, but if you could come up with a better one, feel free to post/accept your own answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a 'package' common to your mappers' namespaces, you can set the log level against the package.
Let's say you have two mappers whose namespaces are `foo.mapper.MapperA` and `foo.mapper.MapperB` respectively.
The common package, in this case, is `foo.mapper`.

When there is no common package, you may have to set log level for each mapper if you want to log all statements.
This is not an ideal solution when you have 500 mappers, obviously.
In such a scenario, I would suggest using an external JDBC logging tool like [JdbcDsLog](https://github.com/adrianshum/jdbcdslog).